# Pixel issue with icon

Tags: font-awesome

If you take a look at the attached picture you can see that the heart is pretty good looking but a strange white spot on the left. The font awesome icon is "heart-o". Do you have any advice on how to fix it?
[image]

Comment: I went [here](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/heart-o/) and I don't see the issue. So it could be anything.

Comment: Without seeing the CSS and HTML this question is unanswerable.